# MVVM List and ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light, observablecollection

So I'm trying to build a small cookbook application using WPF and MVVM light. I've run into a situation where I'm binding a List from the model to the view model. And it works fine for displaying and removing items, but when adding items I couldn't get the display to update.

I came across ObserableCollections which seemed to be just what I wanted, but I'm not sure I'm using them correctly because it seems wrong to be creating a new OC every time. How am I supposed to be retrieving an observable collection when the model is using a list?

Model(s):

```
public class Recipe
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<RecipeIngredient> Ingredients { get; set; }
}

public class RecipeIngredient
{
    // ... //
}
```

ViewModel:

```
 public Recipe SelectedRecipe
{
    get
    {
        return this.selectedRecipe;
    }
    set
    {
        this.selectedRecipe = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedRecipe");
        RaisePropertyChanged("RecipeIngredients");
    }
}

public ObservableCollection<RecipeIngredient> RecipeIngredients
{
    get 
    {
        return new ObservableCollection<RecipeIngredient>(selectedRecipe.Ingredients.ToList());
    }
}

public RelayCommand<EventArgs> AddIngredientCommand { get; private set; }
public RelayCommand<string> DeleteIngredientCommand { get; private set; }

private void AddIngredient(EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    SelectedRecipe.Ingredients.Add(new RecipeIngredient() { Name = "New Ingredient" }); 
    RaisePropertyChanged("RecipeIngredients");
}

private void DeleteIngredient(string name)
{
    SelectedRecipe.Ingredients = SelectedRecipe.Ingredients.Where(i => i.Name != name).ToList();
    RaisePropertyChanged("RecipeIngredients");
}

public MainViewModel()
{
    DBController db = new DBController();
    recipes = db.GetRecipeList();

    RecipeSelectionChangedCommand = new RelayCommand<SelectionChangedEventArgs>((args) => RecipeSelectionChanged(args));
    SaveRecipeCommand = new RelayCommand<EventArgs>((args) => SaveRecipe(args));    
    AddIngredientCommand = new RelayCommand<EventArgs>((args) => AddIngredient(args));
    DeleteIngredientCommand = new RelayCommand<string>((args) => DeleteIngredient(args));
}
```

Am I way off track here?

Comment: Why do you need your ObservableCollection from your ViewModel as List in your model?

Comment: RecipeIngredients should be instantiated only once, in the constructor. Otherwise, everytime the UI wants to refresh it gets a new instance. Totally unnecessary and can lead to misbehaviour.

Comment: MMVM Light provides lambda expression for the property changed: RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.RecipeIngredients) which makes it more type safe, easier to refactor and easier to mantain.

Comment: Oh wow, thanks for the tip about the lambda, was definitely a pain to refactor.

Comment: @Tomtom - Because originaly I was binding right to SelectedRecipe.Ingredients, but deleting the list and calling RPC would never refresh it until I made an OC property and bound to that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should have read more carefully. If you're displaying the selected recipe's ingredients in an alternate view, you should be using data binding in the view `<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedRecipe.Ingredients}"/>` You could consider using linq to entities (Entity Framework) for ORM..

```
public class RecipeVM
{
    public RecipeVM(Recipe r)
    {
        recipe = r;
    }
    Recipe recipe;
    public int Id 
    { 
        get
        {
            return recipe.Id;
        }
        set
        {
            PropertyChanged("Id");
            recipe.id = value;
        }
    }
    public string Title
    {
        get
        {
            return recipe.Title;
        }
        set
        {
            PropertyChanged("Title");
            recipe.Title = value;
        }
    }
    ObservableCollection<RecipeIngredient> ingredients;
    public ObservableCollection<RecipeIngredient> Ingredients 
    {
        get
        {
            if (ingredients == null)
                ingredients = new ObservableCollection<RecipeIngredient>(recipe.Ingredients);
            return ingredients;
        }
        set
        {
            PropertyChanged("Ingredients");
            ingredients = value;
        }
    }
}
```

You'll need to modify that a bit if you want to keep the collections in sync though..

Comment: "<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedRecipe.Ingredients}"/>" This is exactly what I had before! But when I change the Ingredients (which is List<RecipeIngredient>) and called the RaisePropertyChanged for it, I could never get it to update deletes. Which is why I made the observable collection property and bound it to that.

Comment: Anyway, if you "should" be exposing something that implements `INotifyCollectionChanged` (like `ObservableCollection`) to the UI if you're planning on modifying the collection itself (as opposed to the items inside it). So you can wrap the whole recipe class, i'll add that in a bit.

Comment: It's not that I needed to update the collection outside the VM. It's just that when I would remove an item from List<RecipeIngredients> no amount up NPC could make the view refresh. But I think the example you put up is the process that I was looking for and couldn't find, I appreciate it!

Comment: ^-^ feel free to ask if you have any further questions.. Generally, you should be modifying the oc in this exampe and not the list directly. When you're done with it (e.g. save) you can update the list.